How can I handle native exception in *.so library in my Android application?
I am developing Android application to work with a network printers. Atol printers have their own native library (*.so) for printing text. Under certain circumstances (for example, when specifying an incorrect ip-address), this library throws native exceptions and my app crashes even when my code is wrapped in try { } catch (t: Throwable) { }  !
The following information is displayed in the logcat:
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x630000005d in tid 29523 (RxCachedThreadS), pid 27187 (my.app.package)
How can I handle this native exception in my Kotlin code?
This is my full logcat message:
#00 pc 0000000000654930  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/lib/arm64/libfptr10.so (BuildId: 796f36babce130ad8c1d171dab3c2c061ec463bb)
#01 pc 00000000003f8fb4  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/lib/arm64/libfptr10.so (Fptr10::Ports::TcpPort::tag() const+20) (BuildId: 796f36babce130ad8c1d171dab3c2c061ec463bb)
#02 pc 0000000000453ad0  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/lib/arm64/libfptr10.so (Fptr10::Ports::PosixFastTcpPort::open()+4280) (BuildId: 796f36babce130ad8c1d171dab3c2c061ec463bb)
#03 pc 00000000002d7958  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/lib/arm64/libfptr10.so (Fptr10::FiscalPrinter::Atol::AtolProtocolDetector::open()+1600) (BuildId: 796f36babce130ad8c1d171dab3c2c061ec463bb)
#04 pc 000000000026ae60  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/lib/arm64/libfptr10.so (Fptr10::FiscalPrinter::FiscalPrinterHandle::open()+84) (BuildId: 796f36babce130ad8c1d171dab3c2c061ec463bb)
#05 pc 000000000021cb9c  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/lib/arm64/libfptr10.so (doOpen(void*)+36) (BuildId: 796f36babce130ad8c1d171dab3c2c061ec463bb)
#06 pc 00000000002208b4  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/lib/arm64/libfptr10.so (libfptr_open+200) (BuildId: 796f36babce130ad8c1d171dab3c2c061ec463bb)
#07 pc 0000000000351230  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#08 pc 000000000033a7a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+612) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#09 pc 0000000000510a3c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+1976) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#10 pc 00000000004904b8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#11 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#12 pc 0000000001b23090  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#13 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#14 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#15 pc 00000000004904b8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#16 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#17 pc 0000000000a87dfc  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#18 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#19 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#20 pc 0000000000491368  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+4772) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#21 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#22 pc 00000000004a6534  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#23 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#24 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#25 pc 0000000000490828  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1892) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#26 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#27 pc 0000000000a62bb0  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#28 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#29 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#30 pc 0000000000490828  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1892) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#31 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#32 pc 0000000000a62b94  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#33 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#34 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#35 pc 0000000000490828  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1892) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#36 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#37 pc 0000000000a62b58  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#38 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#39 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#40 pc 0000000000491368  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+4772) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#41 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#42 pc 000000000181908c  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#43 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#44 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#45 pc 00000000004904b8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#46 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#47 pc 0000000000488de8  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#48 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#49 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#50 pc 0000000000491368  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+4772) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#51 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#52 pc 0000000001825c2c  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#53 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#54 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#55 pc 00000000004904b8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#56 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#57 pc 0000000000488de8  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#58 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#59 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#60 pc 0000000000491368  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+4772) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#61 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#62 pc 0000000001823288  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#63 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#64 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#65 pc 0000000000491368  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+4772) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#66 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#67 pc 0000000000488ef8  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#68 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#69 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#70 pc 0000000000491368  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+4772) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#71 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#72 pc 0000000001835688  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#73 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#74 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#75 pc 00000000004904b8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#76 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#77 pc 0000000001835468  /data/app/~~M6zM9JK5PqEGK-hMsQq8qw==/my.app.package-4mOPtsiz1G0iT3vRcop3Vw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex
#78 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#79 pc 0000000000511708  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#80 pc 0000000000491368  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+4772) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#81 pc 00000000003539d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#82 pc 000000000023a008  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar
#83 pc 000000000036daec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.18012138979834229341)+232) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#84 pc 000000000036d3e4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+964) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#85 pc 0000000000351368  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 2452917c4ff69cbb6e75e5512260946b)
#86 pc 000000000201789c  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted)


You can't.  Native crashes like that aren't exceptions, and don't generate or pass back an exception to Java.  In particular SIGSEGV is unrecoverable.  It means the application attempted to access a memory address it doesn't have access to.  At that point, the assumption has to be that memory has been corrupted and that the application needs to shut down for safety.  There is no way to override that behavior.

According to siginfo.h it's: #define SEGV_MAPERR 1 /* address not mapped to object */.

Not sure which JNI wrapper you are using, but the documentation covers this:
https://integration.atol.ru/api-en/?java--android#error-handling
if (fptr.printText() < 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%d [%s]", fptr.errorCode(), fptr.errorDescription()));
}


And if you want to prevent native exceptions, this can only be done in the source code:
https://github.com/farafonov-alexey/node-atol-wrapper/blob/master/src/fptr10.cc

I don't know what your library methods return, but you can always return a nullptr and make the return type nullable. That way you can handle errors internally and log them with  __android_log_print() before returning nullptr.
That way you can see the message in your Logcat.

I see an error message in logcat (attached to the question)
